# How to use a custom type in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
var Location = new Schema({
    x: {
        type: String
    },
    y: {
        type: String
    }
 },{
    _id: false
 });

 var AppSchema = new Schema({
    link: {
        type: String
    },
    location: {
        type: Location
    }
})
```

The above not working and I'm getting the following error:

> Undefined type at `location'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are specific valid types within Mongoose, found here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

If I were you, I'd consider using the `type: Schema.Types.Mixed` type.
To quote the mongoose documentation, it's literally an "anything goes" type.